# How to connect to a database running from a docker container from a k8s cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to configure my Api that is running on a K8 cluster to talk to a database that is hosted on Docker. And I wasn't able to find much when trying to connect an external service locally, everything example would be referring to `none local IP` because when I try to replicate it using the examples I've found, I run into the issue of

`The Endpoints "postgres" is invalid: subset[0].addresses[0].ip: Invalid value: "127.0.0.1": may not be in the loopback range (127.0.0.1/8, ::1/128`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: postgres
subsets:
  - addresses:
    - ip: 127.0.0.1
    ports:
      - port: 5432
```

If there is a reason why I can't use a locally hosted database it would be great if you could explain! Thank you in advance

Comment: Kubernetes is a distributed cluster system.  On which node is the database "locally hosted"?  Can you move the database into the cluster too?  Or if you're just working locally, can you use a lighter-weight tool like Docker Compose instead of Kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

So add another service with name say `database-service.yml` with the following

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgressql
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: <database host Name>
```

Also specify the dbname, password, user, port and db host in a ConfigMap as bellow

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: backend-env
  namespace: mynamespace
data:

  ENVIRONMENT: local

  DB_NAME: <dbname>
  DB_PASSWORD: <password>
  DB_USER: <user>
  DB_PORT: "port number"
  DB_HOST: <host>
```

Comment: so give my service an external name of localhost and place env in the config map? Would I have to specify the env var names to POSTGRES_USER: <user> like this because that's how postgres expects it?

Comment: also why do I have to define a namespace for the config map and not the service?